# Remove CSS class from element with JavaScript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could anyone let me know how to remove a class on an element using JavaScript only?
Please do not give me an answer with jQuery as I can't use it, and I don't know anything about it.

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript This answer has some good examples. Patrick.

Comment: I would suggest that you check jQuery source and its method removeClass.

Comment: `document.getElementById("theID").removeAttribute("class")`

Comment: @SandyGood That will remove ALL classes.

Answer (score 1131, accepted):

The right and standard way to do it is using `classList`. It is now [widely supported in the latest version of most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList):

```
ELEMENT.classList.remove("CLASS_NAME");
```

```js
remove.onclick = () => {
  const el = document.querySelector('#el');
  el.classList.remove("red");
}
```

```css
.red {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div id='el' class="red"> Test</div>
<button id='remove'>Remove Class</button>
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList

Comment: FWIW, this works for me on FF 7.0.1, and Chromium 16.0.910.0

Comment: Very nice! That is so much simpler than regular expressions and splitting `className` into parts and manually traversing them.

Comment: @dzhioev - I believe because it is relatively new and not supported in older browsers (IE support starts at IE10)

Comment: On the MDN page there is a shim provided for older browsers.

Comment: This is probably the [article about removing a class with fallback](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/classlist-in-firefox-3-6/) he was talking about.

Comment: This gets even better with [this polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/blob/master/classList.js).

Comment: ELEMENT.classList has both 'add' and 'remove', btw.

Comment: Checked with Chromium in Ubuntu 14.04, and it works as well. So apparently they've caught up.

Comment: Works in mobile Chrome/30.0.0.0

Comment: More about classList support
[http://caniuse.com/#search=classList](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList) and [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList#Browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Best answer here! Adds the least complexity to your JS if you need to do this in plain JS.

Comment: classList also can toggle() ,add() and check for class (contains()) and support multiple class operations. I think this is the best answer (+1)

Comment: I just checked the [can I use link](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList) his feature seems to be working now for all major browsers except for Opera Mini and partial support for IE 11

Comment: 10 years later. I think it's the best solution.

Comment: Why bother checking if the class is there before calling `.remove` if the function doesn't throw any errors if the class isn't there? If you remove the if statement, then JavaScript doesn't have to scan through the class list twice every time it is true.

Comment: IMO checking the condition: `if (el.classList.contains("red"))` isn't necessary, see official `remove()` docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove

Answer (score 532):

```
document.getElementById("MyID").className =
    document.getElementById("MyID").className.replace(/\bMyClass\b/,'');
```

where `MyID` is the ID of the element and MyClass is the name of the class you wish to remove.

---

**UPDATE:** 
To support class names containing dash character, such as "My-Class", use

```
document.getElementById("MyID").className =
  document.getElementById("MyID").className
    .replace(new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)'+ 'My-Class' + '(?:\\s|$)'), ' ');
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that your 1st argument on `replace` must be a regex, so without enclosing it in quotes: `.replace(/\bMyClass\b/,'')`. But then 'MyClass' must to be a literal, otherwise maybe creating the regex dinamically could work: `.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + myClass + '\\b'),'')`

Comment: Also the ID of the element used in your example is "element_id" and not "MyID"

Comment: @PauFracés Check the edit history. The inconsistency got introduced by someone else.

Comment: @ЯegDwight But as Nicholas Pickering suggested, that code wont work until it becomes a regexp. See my previous comment

Comment: The use of the [word boundary metacharacter `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is not suitable here, because the word boundary occurs also between a word character `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and the dash `-` character. Therefore a class name e.g. *'different-MyClass'* would also be replaced, resulting in *'different-'*. There is a better solution which [matches whitespace characters around the class name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9959811/686534).

Comment: I'm also removing a space if its there: `domNode.className.replace(new RegExp(" ?\\b"+cssClass+"\\b"),'')`

Comment: ill just copy paste this here since this where google leads me to not the page with right answer linked in Adam comment. `function removeClass(e,c) {e.className = e.className.replace( new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)'+c+'(?!\\S)') ,'');}`

Comment: didn't work in my case but I like your thoughts

Comment: There are faster methods to remove class than using RegExp, especially if you're going to use it as a polyfill. See http://jsperf.com/removeclass-methods

Comment: IE says the object doesnt support replace....

Comment: If there are multiple instances of the class, for example: `class1 My-Class My-Class My-Class My-Class` this regex won't remove all of them. That's because it removes the \s on both sides of a match, which makes the next match invalid because you stole its spaces!

Comment: What worked for me was replacing `'(?:\\s|$)'` with `'(?=\\s|$)'` (turning it from a non-capture group to positive lookahead). It checks if the space exists without matching it. If you do this you can also make the replacement text `''` instead of `' '` because you're leaving a space (or the end of the line) untouched.

Answer (score 62):

Here's a way to bake this functionality right into all DOM elements:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.removeClass = function(remove) {
    var newClassName = "";
    var i;
    var classes = this.className.split(" ");
    for(i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if(classes[i] !== remove) {
            newClassName += classes[i] + " ";
        }
    }
    this.className = newClassName;
}
```

Comment: Very elegant and most applicable to the question.

Comment: Add an if wrapper [if (typeof HTMLElement.prototype.removeClass !== "function") {]  to make this answer most elegant in case browsers add support for removeClass in the future..

Comment: @Matthew A logoical programmatic way. Appreciate it. Looks cross-browser too. Is it???

Comment: You can also split classes by \t \n \r and \s+, your split-nonregex doesn't take that into account.

Comment: Add a trim() at the end of return to remove redundant spaces when function is used more then once (such as toggling an active/deactivate state).

Comment: @Sam, Added a trim before setting newClassName and tested in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bs2o7wgz/1/

Answer (score 47):

```
div.classList.add("foo");
div.classList.remove("foo");
```

More at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList

Comment: Nice, too bad supports starts with IE 10 and Android 3. Why they didn't code this stuff 10 years ago?..

Comment: @Andrew To be honest the entire world of web technologies looks like a big pile of ideas thrown together without system or consistency...

Answer (score 44):

Try this:

```
function hasClass(ele, cls) {
  return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}
    
function removeClass(ele, cls) {
  if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
    ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
  }
}
```

Comment: `el.className.replace(/(\s|^)someclass(\s|$)/, ' ')` If you aren't feeling like creating a helper function. :)

Comment: Why \\s, and not just \s ? Wondering.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash

Answer (score 27):

**Edit**

Okay, complete re-write.
It's been a while, I've learned a bit and the comments have helped.

```
Node.prototype.hasClass = function (className) {
    if (this.classList) {
        return this.classList.contains(className);
    } else {
        return (-1 < this.className.indexOf(className));
    }
};

Node.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
    if (this.classList) {
        this.classList.add(className);
    } else if (!this.hasClass(className)) {
        var classes = this.className.split(" ");
        classes.push(className);
        this.className = classes.join(" ");
    }
    return this;
};

Node.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {
    if (this.classList) {
        this.classList.remove(className);
    } else {
        var classes = this.className.split(" ");
        classes.splice(classes.indexOf(className), 1);
        this.className = classes.join(" ");
    }
    return this;
};
```

---

**Old Post**

---

I was just working with something like this. Here's a solution I came up with...

```
// Some browsers don't have a native trim() function
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype,'trim', {
        value: function() {
            return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
        },
        writable:false,
        enumerable:false,
        configurable:false
    });
}
// addClass()
// first checks if the class name already exists, if not, it adds the class.
Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype,'addClass', {
    value: function(c) {
        if(this.className.indexOf(c)<0) {
            this.className=this.className+=' '+c;
        }
        return this;
    },
    writable:false,
    enumerable:false,
    configurable:false
});
// removeClass()
// removes the class and cleans up the className value by changing double 
// spacing to single spacing and trimming any leading or trailing spaces
Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype,'removeClass', {
    value: function(c) {
        this.className=this.className.replace(c,'').replace('  ',' ').trim();
        return this;
    },
    writable:false,
    enumerable:false,
    configurable:false
});
```

Now you can call `myElement.removeClass('myClass')`

or chain it: `myElement.removeClass("oldClass").addClass("newClass");`

Comment: I'm very late here, but I have an example case where this would not work:

Consider an element that has classes testClass and testClass2. (class="testClass testClass2")

We wish to remove testClass from the element.

Result using your method: class="2"

This is why breaking it into an array is favourable. Of course, it is still possible to achieve the correct result using pure string manipulation, but it becomes more complex. If you don't want a mess of code you'll need to use Regex.

The advantage of using an array is that the code is easily readable.

Comment: @YM_Industries You're right! I'll edit my post.

Comment: @Knu Native `Element.classList.add()` doesn't support the space in `"one two"`.

Comment: @Knu What about `".one.two"`, `("one", "two", ...)`, `["one","two"]`, `{"0":"one","1":"two"}`... etc. I'll leave non-standard parameter handling to the person implementing their code.  :)

Comment: `classList` **isn't** supported in **IE < 11**. You can use regex instead : `this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + className + '(?:\\s|$)'), '').trim();`

Comment: @Flox No need for that, non-'classList' browsers are already handled. Not to mention that regex is fairly heavy and not needed in this instance.

Comment: i dont think `.contains` is supported, by older browsers.

Comment: Having `Element.prototype` instead of `Node.prototype` makes more sense because only elements would have `class`.

Answer (score 20):

It's very simple, I think.

```
document.getElementById("whatever").classList.remove("className");
```

Comment: This has poor cross-browser support. Internet Explorer doesn't support it in any version prior to 10. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList#Browser_compatibility

Comment: This to me seems like the right answer. If you are worried about cross browser use a polyfill.

https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js

Comment: @ShannonPoole Sometimes you just need to do a simple task in an IE8-compatible way and you don't want it to depend on library support or a heavy polyfill.

Comment: @acjay and sometimes you throw caution to the wind and just follow the modern standard :)

Comment: To support IE, you can use **regex** instead : `this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + className + '(?:\\s|$)'), '').trim();`

Answer (score 10):

try:

```
function removeClassName(elem, name){
    var remClass = elem.className;
    var re = new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '( |$)');
    remClass = remClass.replace(re, '$1');
    remClass = remClass.replace(/ $/, '');
    elem.className = remClass;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var element = document.getElementById('example_id');
var remove_class = 'example_class';

element.className = element.className.replace(' ' + remove_class, '').replace(remove_class, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this JS snippet code :

First of all, I reach all the classes then according to index of my target class, I set **className = ""**.

```
Target = document.getElementsByClassName("yourClass")[1];
Target.className="";
```

Comment: This is not a good solution because it will remove all classes from the element.

Answer (score -7):

```
document.getElementById("whatever").className += "classToKeep";
```

With the plus sign ('+') appending the class as opposed to overwriting any existing classes

Comment: Wrong, += adds a class to the existing list of classes

Comment: You could add space before newly added class to make it less wrong.