# How do you cancel/disable a CSS selector?

Tags: css

I'm working on a [woothemes.com](http://www.woothemes.com) Wordpress template (specifically the 'Simplicity' theme) and I am trying to follow the rules they set out for manipulating CSS, which word for word is:

> WARNING! DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!
>
> To make it easy to update your theme, you should not edit the styles
>   in this file. Instead use  the custom.css file to add your styles. You
>   can copy a style from this file and paste it in  custom.css and it
>   will override the style in this file. You have been warned! :)

Pretty obvious I think. So by following the rules, how do I effectively cancel out an entire CSS selector (I think I could manually set each selector element to 0, but is there a more elegant way of doing this?):

```
.entry img, img.thumbnail { margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #ddd; background:#fff;  

    /* Box Shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

In pseudo code I'd write:

```
.entry img, img.thumbnail { 

       clear-all-styles;

}
```

But obviously that won't work :)

Comment: I think you'll have to manually set all of the styles to `0`, there isn't (at least, as far as I am aware) something to remove all styles like you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel some CSS Style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827200/cancel-some-css-style)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such way of disabling styles in css, you'll have to do it manually as you do it in your first example.

As a matter of fact, that is the same way that css guru Eric Meyer uses to reset styles in his famous [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) file.

Comment: Hmm, this is an excellent point thinking of all the reset files I've seen before. Would be easy just to say 'RESET', but obviously that's not a possibility. Thank you for introducing me to Eric Meyer!

Comment: In CSS there is no RESET, as you put it, because it should never be needed in the first place if browsers did actually followed the CSS spec. I mean, in the CSS spec there are default values for each property, if all browsers implemented these default values as published in the spec then there would be no need to `reset.css` files .