# I need to remove a div by class with javascript (not jquery)

Tags: javascript

I need to remove the class YoPowered, it is the class of a div. I need it to be removed.

Can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove CSS class from element with JavaScript (no jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery)

Comment: Remove the class on the element or remove all elements with that class?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll() is 90% as good as jQuery for dom selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("YoPowered");

for(var i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  elems[i].className = elems[i].className.replace(/YoPowered/, '');
}
```

You could optionally replace the `document.getElementsByClassName("YoPowered")` with `document.querySelectorAll('.YoPowered')`

See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html for compatibility if that's an issue.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FHTMLCollection). Your code will not work properly.

Comment: I see your point, edited to handle live collection