# Remove the hover selector from an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to remove the "hover" selector from an element using code (html, css, or js?)  I'm finding that whenever I open my side nav on a mobile site I'm creating, the first element is always "hover" for some reason even though I don't tap it.

Comment: Please edit your answer in order to provide more specific info and code

Comment: Persnaps: `$(".active).removeClass(".active");`

Comment: @agconti `jQuery == JS` ... `JS != jQuery`

Comment: You're talking about ":active" not ".active" right?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That is for classes.  I'm asking about selectors. As aquinas mentions, its :active not .active.

Comment: This seems like weird behavior. Can you reproduce it in a jsfiddle? Does it only happen on certain devices (iOS or something?).

Comment: @aquinas Only on touchscreens.  Wondering if when I hit my menu button it thinks I hit the top option in the navigation when it opens as well.  Its using the sidr jquery plugin.

Comment: EDIT:  It's actually in :hover state.  More specifically this is what I see in the dev tools:  .sidr ul li:hover>a

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan This is not a duplicate of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery.  That one asks about removing a class from an element, mine is asking about removing a selector from an element.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code or detailed info it's just a wild guess, but try to add this to your stylesheet:

```
* {
   outline: none;
}
```

*Note*: isn't wishful when you care for accessibility.

Comment: the *Note* is actually a **Really Important** *Note*

Answer (score -1):

You could simply set the elements class to nothing.

`document.getElementById("whatever").className = "";`

Comment: using this you'll remove any possible class

Comment: if you wanted to keep a particular class you could just reset the class
`document.getElementById("whatever").className = "";
document.getElementById("whatever").className = "classToKeep";`

Comment: and next time provide the source of your *idea* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery or simply mark the question as duplicate

Comment: More importantly, he's saying the :active selector, not a class name. As in: "a:active" Or: http://jsfiddle.net/C5bX4/