# How to change a span label's class using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html element like this:

```
<dd><span class="label label-success" id="status">Production</span></dd>
```

I want to change it to

```
<dd><span class="label label-warning" id="status">Idle</span>
```

based on a ws.socket message.

```
setTimeout(function(){
            window.ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8088/sock/123');
            window.ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                field.value = "Idle"
            };
            window.ws.onclose = function (evt){

            }
            window.ws.onopen = function (evt){

            }

        }, 500);
```

I want to change the value from Production to Idle and the class to "label label-warning".
I know to change the value I would do this:

```
var field = document.getElementById("status")
```

but I'm not exactly sure how to change the class and would using field.value be the correct way to change a span text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have jQuery, use it!

```
$("#status").text("Idle").removeClass("label-success").addClass("label-warning");
```

Or just `.toggleClass("label-success label-warning");`

Comment: How to change span class name and aria-label if it does not have id name?

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery

Try this

```
$('#status').text('Your Text')  //For setting text
$('#status').removeClass('label-success').addClass('label-warning')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting to use JavaScript and not jQuery, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery). You can easily set the class by just saying:

```
document.getElementById("whatever").className = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the class (this is much more convenient using jQuery):

```
document.getElementsById('status').setAttribute("class","label label-warning");
```

To change the value of the span text:

```
document.getElementsById('status').innerHTML = "Production";
```