# a class none via css?

Tags: html, css

My normal desktop site has links like this

```
<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="template.html"><div class="text_14">Feature Article</div>  </a>
```

But for my phone site i need the "class" to be gone. So that the link will open as a subpage instead of a fancy box.

So i tried

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px)  {

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    class: none;
}
```

which doesn't work. So how do i get the class to not be displayed?

Comment: which class you want to hide for mobile device?

Comment: You cannot change your HTML through CSS. CSS is used to change the *appearance* of elements (often based on the class they have), but not their actual attributes.

You can remove the class from the element through Javascript.

Comment: @GolezTrol how do i do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Javascript for removing class from HTML element
Since you are using fancybox, I assume you have included jQuery too so following code should work if you open the page in mobile device.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        if($(window).innerWidth() <= 480){
            $('a.various').removeClass('various').removeClass('fancybox.iframe');
        }
    })
</script>
```