# JavaScript- how to find elements by class and remove this class

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

I have to find element by class  name and remove this class.

I tried to use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('error-sign-up').removeClass('error-sign-up');
```

but I got an error -Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Comment: `.removeClass` is a jQuery method, it is not included in a HTMLCollection that `getElementsByClassName()` returns.

Comment: Also, `removeClass` is jQuery method, here's the dupe for that -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
$('span.error-sign-up').each(function(index,item){
  $(item).removeClass('error-sign-up');
})
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fw1auznf/1/)