# Remove all classes from SVG using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>    
   .someClass {
            fill:gray;
        }
</style>
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect class="someClass" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
 <svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect class="someClass" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
 <svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect class="a" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

How to remove all classes(.someClass) need to remove only in .someClass in document without using id?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass

Comment: Did not the provided answers work for you?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't call `.removeClass()` on a SVG, unfortunately.

Use .attr() instead.

```
$('.someClass').attr('class','');
```

additional sources:

[Martin Wolf](http://martinwolf.org/2014/12/11/adding-and-removing-classes-from-svg-elements-with-jquery/)

[Similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass)

Comment: That will, of course, remove **all** classes. Which is fine for the quoted HTML, but...

Comment: You could use the [form of `attr` that takes a function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) as the second argument. This would give you the old value and you could do a `replaceAll()` to remove it.

Comment: Just wanted to add to this there is currently a [PR in jquery to change removeClass so this won't be an issue.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/2465)

Answer (score 7):

This ( `$('.someClass').attr('class','');` ) will delete all the classes of all elements with class `someClass`.

---

This should do the trick ( retains other classes):

```
$(".someClass").each(function(){

     var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
     var otherClasses = "";
     for(var i = 0; i<classes.length; ++i){
        if(classes[i] !== "someClass"){
            otherClasses += classes[i] + " ";
        }
     }

     $(this).attr("class",otherClasses);

});
```

---

Thanks *@xehpuk* for his comments.

Comment: This doesn't retain other classes, e.g. "someClass2".

Comment: hmm yeah but better than `$('.someClass').attr('class','');`

Comment: Now this won't remove "someClass" if it's at the end of the string. And it'll still remove "troublesomeClass ".

Comment: @codehx simply use `.replace(/\bsomeClass\b/, '')`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**removeAttr**](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/), which will find all the matched elements and will remove the given attribute. 
 In your case this code will find all elements with class `someClass` and will remove the attribute `class`. 
 And the good in this code is that it will not leave an empty attribute.

```
$('.someClass').removeAttr( "class" );
```

Comment: For the specific case I think this is actually more correct than the answer with the many upvotes because that will leave an empty attribute...

Comment: And what happend if the element have more than one class?

Comment: @YoannAugen in that case this answer is not advisable, but it satisfying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. For more info see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2156090/909535

```
rect.classList.remove("CLASS_NAME");
```