# Vanilla Javascript - Adding class to element 1 and remove class from element 2 on click of element 1

Tags: javascript

I've been told I can no longer use jQuery on a project I'm building, so I'm forced to use vanilla Javascript which can sometimes be way over my head. I'm hoping to simply convert this jQuery to js. I've searched and searched on Stack Overflow to no avail, but I feel like it shouldn't be that difficult. Any help would be amazing!

```
$('.navbuttoncontainer a').on( 'click', function() {
$('.navbuttoncontainer .current').removeClass('current');
$(this).addClass('current');
```

Comment: You've searched and searched? what about this question, which is a duplicate of another question, with 21 answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery

Comment: And what's your relevant, "[MCVE]" HTML?

Comment: What are you having problems with, attaching an event handler, getting an element by selector or adding and removing a css class?

Comment: For more examples of jQuery functionality and its vanilla DOM equivalent, see http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 5):

You could attach a `click` event listener to the `.navbuttoncontainer` element.

Then determine whether the `a` element was clicked by checking the tag name of the target element (`e.target`). Use the `.add()`/`.remove()` methods on the [`classList` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) of the element in order to add/remove the class.

```js
document.querySelector('.navbuttoncontainer').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var target = e.target;
  
  if (target.tagName === 'A') {
    e.currentTarget.querySelector('.current').classList.remove('current');
    target.classList.add('current');
  }
});
```

```css
.current {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbuttoncontainer">
  <a class="current">Initially current item</a>
  <a>Second item</a>
  <a>Third item</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All modern browsers have support for `document.querySelector`/`document.querySelectorAll`, which are essentially the same thing as the jQuery $ function.

(For supported browser info check out http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector.

Instead of calling `addClass`/`removeClass` on a jQuery object, the DOM API exposes a property of elements called `className`. This is same as the `class` attribute on an element:

this.className = 'current';

Lastly, event handlers are registered with the `addEventListener` function. The arguments are the event name and the event handler function.