# How to remove class of a tag child in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I remove class active. Below is my code, first I find id tag then class but this code is not working:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element1 = document.getElementById('grid3d');
  var remove_class = 'active';

  element1.className = element1.className.replace(' ' + remove_class, '').replace(remove_class, '');
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid3d">Hello World

  <figure ">Click the button to remove the class attribute from the h1 element.</figure>
    
    <figure class="active ">Click the button to remove the class attribute from the h1 element.</figure>
    
    <figure>Click the button to remove the class attribute from the h1 element.</figure>
    </div>
    <button onclick="myFunction() ">Try it</button>
```

Comment: use jquery it has just two line code //ex $("element1").removeClass("active");

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: give id to figure tag in your code

Comment: that we not able to add this is a plugin and we want to remove active class from all figure tags do you have any idea how it works ?

Comment: try this document.getElementById("grid3d").className = "";

Comment: that I have done but it works only at which class and ID is on same tag and in my case id is on parent and class is in child tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove CSS class from element with JavaScript (no jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery)

Comment: @caramba First I saw all those answers but those all solution has not work that's the reason I posted this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this snippet

```js
function myFunction() {
  var fig = document.querySelectorAll('figure');

  for (var i = 0; i < fig.length; i++) {
    if (fig[i].className == "active") {
      fig[i].className = "";
    }
  }

}
```

```css
.active {
  color: purple;  
}
```

```html
<div id="grid3d">Hello World

  <figure>Click the button to remove the class attribute from the h1 element.</figure>

  <figure class="active">Click the button to remove the class attribute from the h1 element.</figure>

  <figure>Click the button to remove the class attribute from the h1 element.</figure>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Great this works I like this code testing it with my all conditions

Comment: I have one more question to you how we can get current child of figure tag which has active class

Comment: use this if you have only one child element         `fig[i].children[0].className`

Comment: First, check the length of children. and then use the above code.

Answer (score 1):

you can try use classList.remove() function on figure element

```
function myFunction() {
  var element1 = document.getElementById('grid3d'),
      remove_class = 'active',
      figureEl = element1.querySelector('.' + remove_class);


  figureEl.className.remove(remove_class);
}
```

I hope it will works.

Comment: I have one more question to you how we can get current child of figure tag which has active class –

Comment: In the similar way like this:
el.querySelector('figure.active'); // where el can be a figure element

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would like to remove the id of the second `<figure>`. You can use the JS method `removeAttribute()`. It enables you to remove any attribute from a element tag.

```js
var removeClass = function(selector) {
  var el = document.querySelector(selector);
  el.removeAttribute('id');
}
```

```css
#active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Remove #active! from the second figure tag

  <figure>Click the button to remove the class attribute from the h1 element.</figure>

  <figure id="active">Click the button to remove the class attribute from the h1 element.</figure>

  <figure>Click the button to remove the class attribute from the h1 element.</figure>
</div>
<button onclick="removeClass('#active')">Try it</button>
```

Comment: You have completely change my condition as I mention this is a plugin any other to fix this with my same code

Comment: You need to work a little instead of asking for code correction. Do you want to delete a specific element or all elements that have .active?