# Trigger animation on background url change

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm dynamically changing the background image of a div with Javascript.

When the image appears in the div, I want a grey-scale to color transition to happen. But it only happens the first time, if I change the image again the effect does not work.

How do I go about triggering the CSS3 animation when the background url changes ?

**I'm steering clear of Jquery on this one, vanilla js only please**

```
.slide {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
animation: filter-animation 8s;
-webkit-animation: filter-animation 8s;
}
```

--

```
@keyframes filter-animation {
    0% {
        filter: grayscale(100%);
        transition: all 8s ease;
        100% {

            filter: grayscale(0%);
        }
    }
}
```

JS render code:

```
function renderCurrentSlide() {
    document.getElementById('slide').style.background = "url('" + Image.image_data + "') no-repeat top center fixed";
    document.getElementById('image-title').innerHTML = Image.title;
    document.getElementById('image-caption').innerHTML = Image.desc;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slider-container">
    <div class="slider-main">
        <div id="gallery">
            <ul class="images">
                <li class="slide" id="slide"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="caption-and-title-holder">
            <div id="image-title"></div>
            <div id="image-caption"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your javascript code as well?

Comment: What are you currently doing to trigger the animation?

Comment: @GonrasKarols I posted in main question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's basically just a CSS3 animation attached to the slide class, so this is probably why it only happens once.. Not sure how to fix tho.

Comment: Could you also add the HTML code? How are your DOM elements laid out? You could try to use Javascript to remove the class, then readd the same class to trigger the animation again.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery

Comment: Yes, but the animation needs a "trigger". When and how are you initiating the animation? Show all the relevant code (HTML as well.).

Comment: @ScottMarcus The 'animation: filter-animation 8s;' is attached to the .slide class, I guess it's triggered on load. I've tried removing and adding a 'fade' class on each new image, but that's not working currently.

Comment: And, where is the `.slide` class in the code you've posted. And, where is the `renderCurrentSlide` function called from. Not trying to annoy you, but post *all* the relevant code, not just fragments.

Comment: [Sigh] You still haven't posted the code that calls `renderCurrentSlide` or the code that declares the `Image` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a class that only handles the animation and then

1. remove the animation class
2. trigger reflow
3. add the animation class

```js
var images = [
  'http://dummyimage.com/500x500/ff000/ffffff?text=1',
  'http://dummyimage.com/500x500/00ff00/ffffff?text=2'
]

function renderCurrentSlide() {
  var slide = document.getElementById('slide');
  slide.classList.remove('filter-animation');
  slide.style.background = "url('" + images[0] + "') no-repeat top center fixed";
  void slide.offsetWidth;
  slide.classList.add('filter-animation');
}

//for demo only
renderCurrentSlide();
images.shift();
setTimeout(renderCurrentSlide, 10000);
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.filter-animation {
  animation: filter-animation 8s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: filter-animation 8s forwards;
}

@keyframes filter-animation {
  0% {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
  }
  100% {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-main">
    <div id="gallery">
      <ul class="images">
        <li class="slide" id="slide"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="caption-and-title-holder">
      <div id="image-title"></div>
      <div id="image-caption"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

credit: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/