# delete elements in javascript (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudflare-workers

How to remove element with Javascript?
To do this, I follow the code:

```
function removeClassName(elem, name){
    var remClass = elem.className;
    var re = new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '( |$)');
    remClass = remClass.replace(re, '$1');
    remClass = remClass.replace(/ $/, '');
    elem.className = remClass;
}
```

Ref: [Remove CSS class from element with JavaScript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery)

And this code:
    https://gist.github.com/ParveenBhadooOfficial/9c94d4bd814542d5fed5ee69e9470139

How can the above two codes be used simultaneously?

Comment: `elem.classList.remove(name)` is a much better way to remove a class from an element... I'm not sure why you went all the way down to pick a decade-old answer when there's a modern one with literally 100x more upvotes...

Answer (score 0):

To remove the class name using Javascript :

```
function removeClassName(elem, name){
   elem.classList.remove(name);
}
```

Comment: How to use your code with This : https://gist.github.com/ParveenBhadooOfficial/9c94d4bd814542d5fed5ee69e9470139