# Deleting class from an element

Tags: javascript

I'm making a task board project.
Must say I'm using only HTML, CSS, JS, and nothing else right now.
I'm making a fade-in effect to the newly added note (`ul` element), and I would like to delete the fade-in class from the previously added note.
this is a chunk of my code that displays the note inside the `div`.

```js
function displayAllTasks(allTasks){
  taskNotesDiv.innerHTML = "";
  for(const task of allTasks){
    const index = allTasks.indexOf(task);
    const note = `
      <div class"noteDiv">
        <ul class="fadeInNote">
          <button type="button" onclick="deleteTask(${index})">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-trash deleteButton"></i>
          </button>
          <li>Task: ${task.task}</li>
          <li>Description: ${task.textArea}</li>
          <li>Date: ${task.date}</li>
          <li>Time: ${task.time}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    `
    taskNotesDiv.innerHTML += note;
  }   
}
```

I tried already another function to delete it but with no success.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: an `element` has a `classList` property that you can `.add`, `.remove` or `.toggle` for example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove CSS class from element with JavaScript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery)

Comment: Already tried that, and it won't work - giving me an error because the element hasn't been created yet as it's innerHTML creation.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't add HTML elements as a string. If you use `let note = document.createElement("div")` then you can easily add and remove classes with `note.classList.remove("someclass")`

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Would you write me a sample so I would know what to do in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple approaches, but my approach is to create element using `document.createElement` . The modified JS will become:

```js
function displayAllTasks(allTasks) {
    last_ul = null;  // store the last ul element added
    taskNotesDiv.innerHTML = "";
    for (const task of allTasks) {
        const index = allTasks.indexOf(task);

        let noteDiv = document.createElement('div');
        noteDiv.classList.add('noteDiv');
        
        note_ul = document.createElement('ul');
        note_ul.classList.add('fadeInNote');
        note_ul.innerHTML = `
            <button type="button" onclick="deleteTask(${index})">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-trash deleteButton"></i>
            </button>
            <li>Task: ${task.task}</li>
            <li>Description: ${task.textArea}</li>
            <li>Date: ${task.date}</li>
            <li>Time: ${task.time}</li>`

        noteDiv.appendChild(note_ul);
        // if it is not the first element, then remove the class from previous
        if (last_ul != null) {
            last_ul.classList.remove('fadeInNote');
        }
        last_ul = note_ul;  // this becomes previous for next iteration
        taskNotesDiv.appendChild(noteDiv);
    }
    // remove class of the last element
    if (last_ul != null) {
        last_ul.classList.remove('fadeInNote');
    }
    
}
```